# Nhibernate Restrictions.In Error

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

Finally tracked down my error which is a result of the query.  I have an nhibernate query using a Restrictions.In.  Problem is once query executes if no results returned query throws error immediately.  Is there another restriction that I can use.  I know if I was writing a linq query I could use the .Any to return bool value and go from there is there something similar I can do in this instance?

carMake is passed in

```
        myQuery.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Car)
           .Where(Restrictions.In("VIN",
               Trades.Where(x => x.Car.Make.ToLower() == carMake.ToLower())
                   .Select(x => x.Car.PrimaryVIN)
                   .ToList()));
```

Comment: What is `Trades`? Another entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Trades` is a list of objects you can use `.WhereRestrictionOn()` instead. Try this (I split the code for better readability):

```
var vinsWithCarMake = Trades
    .Where(x => x.Car.Make.ToLower() == carMake.ToLower())
    .Select(x => x.Car.PrimaryVIN)
    .ToList<string>();

var carAlias = null;
var result = myQuery.JoinAlias(x => x.Car, () => carAlias)
       .WhereRestrictionOn(() => carAlias.VIN).IsInG<string>(vinsWithCarMake)
       .List();
```